# NOT NULL constraint in long version of wide table

Tags: sql, postgresql

[This question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026226/mysql-long-table-vs-wide-table) suggest that wide tables are faster, but that long tables are more flexible (and I suspect, closer to the theoretical goals of relational databases).

However, in a wide table, I can specify that one or more of the values in a record must be NOT NULL. The whole record will be rejected if any not null constraints are violated. How do I do this in the "long" version, in Postgres? How for example in the referenced question's long version, would I specify that if an "S" size exists, then "M" and "L" records for the same item, must also exist?

What does the theory say about when to choose wide versus long. Is the above an example of when you *must* go wide?

Comment: For that type of constraint you would need a trigger.

Comment: @GordonLinoff so theoretically, this is where you "go wide"? I'm quite interested in the theoretical "canonical advice" of when to go long and when to go wide. I note that on the practical side, a trigger is going to be worse than a not null constraint for maintainability, readability, and probably performance.

Comment: I wouldn't want to get into a design debate yet the proper way to do it would generally be to have separate attributes in a single row. Why are you worried about the row size? There's a lot of storage and indexing behind the scenes for tracking the extra rows anyway. What is the business use exactly? Would it make sense to encode the various combinations of values into a single attribute (while not violating first normal form?) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: @shawnt00 the use case is tracking the attributes of financial instruments. Bonds in particular. They can have many, many attributes, some of which are necessary, others can be specific only to certain instruments. So in a wide table there will be many wasted columns, because there are maybe only 20 columns common to all bonds, but there are over 100 different possible attributes, 80 of which _can_ be NULL. The long version makes this easy, but I sacrifice referential integrity tools. I guess it's just a matter of figuring which is more important. In your opinion, wide is ok even here?

Comment: Joe Celko has done a lot of writing on EAV. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/avoiding-the-eav-of-destruction/

Comment: For dynamic attributes, I'd use a JSONB column.

Comment: Regarding this, `How for example in the referenced question's long version, would I specify that if an "S" size exists, then "M" and "L" records for the same item, must also exist?`, you wouldn't, because they might not.

Comment: is your table for tee-shirt prices too?